# rails - using RE to extract locale from HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

I am using RE to extract locale from `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`. The recommended way provided by [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-client-supplied-information) is:

```
request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
```

Unfortunately, this RE doesn't work in many cases, in which the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is something like `en-US`, `zh-TW` or `zh-CN`. Thus I modified the RE:

```
/^[\w\-\w]{2,5}/
```

This works. Nonetheless, the IDE gives me a warning: `character class has duplicated range: /^[\w\-\w]{2,5}/`.

How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@npinti and @Victor's answers are good from the perspective of "regex". However, they are not useful enough when the topic is "using RE to extract locale from HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in rails". To detect both 2 chars(eg, "en") and 5 chars(eg, "en-US") format properly in rails:

```
# accept_language should be something like 
# "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4" (from chrome)
# however, it may be nil if the client doesn't set accept language in header.
accept_language = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] || ""
# use "match" instead of "scan"!!
match_data = accept_language.match(/^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?/)
I18n.locale = match_data ? match_data[0] : I18n.default_locale
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use next pattern:

```
/^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?$/
```

But commonly lang is a `en_US` format, `_` instead `-`

Comment: I am sorry that your answer doesn't match when the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is actually a 2 chars string. BTW, the header sent by Chrome is "en-US" rather than "en_US".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that within the square brackets, you list any characters you want to match regardless of order, so `[\w-\w]` is the same as `[\w-]`. Changing it to something like so should achieve what you are after: `\w{2}(-\w{2})?`.

For a more stricter control, you can make use of this: `^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?$`.

Comment: This doesn't match when the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is actually a 2 chars string. However, this gave me a clue to the answer. +1

Comment: @Brian: I have made a minor amendment to the regex. The second part(-GB) is now optional, so it will match `en` and `en-GB`. The danger with the one you have proposed is that it can also match `a-s-v`.

Comment: You are right. My regex is not good enough. However, your regex doesn't work. Would you like to test it?

Comment: @Brian: Sorry my bad, for some reason I managed to invert the casing on the letters.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `.split(';', 2).first` ?